# What to #include?

Tags: c++, include

I understand if `a.h` includes `b.h` and I don't declare anything from `b.h` in my header including only `a.h` is good practice.  If I were to declare anything from `b.h` in my header then I should include both `a.h` and `b.h` to make my header self-sufficient.

In my header I do declare both `class A` from `a.h` and `class B` from `b.h`.  However, `class A` depends on `class B`, so I always use them together.  I never use `class B` independently of `class A`.  In this case does it still make sense to include both `a.h` and `b.h`?

**a.h**

```
#include "b.h"
#include <queue>

class A
{

private:
   std::queue<B> mFoo;
}
```

In my actual code I think it makes my intention clearer when I include just my event system for example and not a number of includes that seem superfluous to me.

Comment: You should not rely in indirect includes. If you need `b.h`, then include it regardless.

Comment: Include all of your direct dependencies. Don't include things that your dependencies depend on unless they're also direct dependencies of yours.

Comment: To be clear, by declaring something in my code I make it a dependency?  Therefore, regardless of what I think, I should #include it.

Comment: In my view, if `class A` requires `class B` and ensures it is included, you don't need `b.h` as well as `a.h`.  I suspect that's going against the prevailing view.  If `class B` is 'accidentally' included by `a.h` rather than 'necessarily' included, then it would be different.

Comment: @user870130: In addition to what others said, go ahead and learn about forward declarations.

Comment: @juanchopanza Even for a derived class?

Comment: @user870130 If you need the class definition, then yes. Whether a class is derived or not should make no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You should always include direct dependencies: if **a** depends directly on **b** and **c**, even if **b** already includes **c**, **a** should include both.

**Be explicit about your dependencies.** You should not rely on the fact that some other module already depends on the module you'd have to include. You never know how the dependency tree will change in the future.

In this regard, having implicit dependencies makes your code fragile.

---

To make sure you don't redefine something by including it twice, you can put [header guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) inside your header files:

```
#ifndef GRANDFATHER_H
#define GRANDFATHER_H

struct foo {
    int member;
};

#endif /* GRANDFATHER_H */
```

You could also use

```
#pragma once
```

But not every compiler supports it.

That way even if the preprocessor will step on same include more than once, It won't re-include the code.

Comment: If the reason your code is using B is because A uses B, and then subsequently A is revised not to use B, your code using B is not going to work until you revise it not to use B either.  So, I'm not convinced by the "you never know how the dependency tree will change in the future" argument.

Comment: If A is using B, then it's direct dependency. If it's using C it's also direct dependency. Now, even if B is using C, you still need to include C in A. That's because of posible changes of B in the future:

**B: include C** _<- this can change, so_
**A: include B, C** _<- C is required_

Comment: Well, sometimes you can get away with forward declarations. And there are some other tricks.

Answer (score 0):

My rule: Given some random header `foo.h`, the following should compile clean, and preferably should link and run as well:

```
#include "foo.h"
int main () {}
```

Suppose `foo.h` doesn't contain any syntax errors (i.e., a source file that includes it in the context you intended compiles clean) but the above nonetheless doesn't compile. This almost always means there are some missing `#include` directives in `foo.h`.

What this doesn't tell you is whether all of the headers included in `foo.h` truly are needed. I have a handy little script that checks the above. If it passes, it creates a copy of `foo.h` and progressively comments out `#include` directives and sees if those modified versions of `foo.h` pass the above test. Any that do pass are indicative of suspect superfluous `#include` directives.

The problem is that the `#include` directives deemed to be superfluous might not be superfluous. Suppose `foo.h` defines class `Foo`, which has data members of type `Bar` and `Baz` (not pointers, members). The header `foo.h` correctly includes both `bar.h` and `baz.h` because that is where those two classes are defined. Suppose `bar.h` happens to include `baz.h`. As the author of `foo.h`, I don't care. I should still include both of those headers in `foo.h` because `foo.h` has direct dependencies on both of those other headers. My script will complain about suspect superfluous headers in this case. Those complaints are hints, not mandates.

On the other hand, fixing `foo.h` so that my simple test program above compiles clean is a mandate.